# TRANSPOSE and leave 3 blank cells between each outputted cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to transpose a column of different values into a row with only uniques, where there is a space of three empty cells between each outputted value. [current output vs. desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E52j3.png) If anyone has an idea of how to approach this, your input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks y'all

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=transpose(flatten(index({unique(A2:A11),
iferror(sequence(countunique(A2:A11),3)/0)})))
```

Essentially, we are creating a virtual array with the unique values in A2:A11 and 3 blank columns, [flattening](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en) it and finally transposing it.